# How do I force Grails to refresh dependencies using my local Maven repository?

Tags: maven, grails, groovy, aether

I have 2 code bases, a Gradle managed Groovy project and a Grails (2.4) Web app project. The Grails app uses the Groovy project as a dependency. My problem right now is that the Grails app can't seem to get the latest SNAPSHOT build of the Groovy one, which, so far, I've been installing only into my local Maven repository. I've read the [documentation about changing dependencies](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.1/guide/conf.html#changingDependencies) but even if I set the `mavenLocal` and `mavenCentral` `updatePolicy` to `'always'` in `BuildConfig.groovy`, I still get error messages caused by the dependency to the Groovy project being outdated. Admittedly, I don't fully understand the dependency management mechanisms employed by Grails 2.4.

Comment: Have you double checked the project version numbers? Is your Groovy project being published properly to the local Maven repo? Are you publishing the correct projects? I have sometimes only published a sub-project and wondered why my changes aren't appearing. Are you depending on the correct projects?

Comment: I figured out the problem is that I'm expecting a method I placed somewhere else. I feel silly now.

Comment: For grails 3, run the gradle build with the --refresh-dependencies switch.